# Multiple GLSurfaceView moving at the same time

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, java-native-interface

I am facing an strange issue not sure why this is happening.

I have a `Java` based `Activity` which has a `LinearLayout`. This `LinearLayout` consists of two `GLSurfaceView`. All the associated methods of `GLSurfaceView` like `OnDraw`, `SurfaceChanged` etc are moving call down to `JNI` layer. Inside the `JNI` layer I am drawing a cube using `OpenGLES`. I have also created a touch listener and have associated it with first `GLSurfaceView`. Once I get a touch event I move the call to `JNI` layer and randomly rotate the first cube.

Problem is when I rotate my first cube both the cubes rotates at exactly same angle. I have debugged this issue for last four hours and I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong in my logic. But for some unknown reason when I make change in one GLSurfaceView other cube changes automatically.

Any ideas? Similar issues? Guess?

**Update**

I am using same context i.e. my activity for both `GLSurfaceView`. Basically I have a class inside C++ which draws cube through opengles. Now I am successfully creating two cubes and displaying them simultaneously. Both cubes have different texture on them which I am passing via Java layer. My c++ class has a method which randomly rotates the cube. Problem is if I call method of one cube to rotate it other automatically rotates at same angle no make what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved there was one logical mistake in my code

Sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, I'd guess you are initializing your GLSurfaceView's using the same context. When sharing a context changing one will change the other because they will share the same GL10 instance in the Renderer. I don't program in android, but in general you'd use multiple "viewports" to display different things.

Comment: Yes, I am using same context to initialize the GLSurfaceView but both the cubes have different texture on it. Is this the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Say that your first GLSurfaceView is on the first left side of your screen, and the second is on the second right half. One idea is to check what side the coordinates x, y of the motionEvent belongs to. And then pass rotation and translation accordingly.